# alternativa a LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL en django 1.9

Tags: python, django

Se que aun en Django 1.9 funciona `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, lo que pasa que quiero una alternativa a `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`

ya que el soporte a esta se eliminará en Django 1.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según las notas de version en linea `LOGIN_URL` y `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` no serán desaprobados en la versión de Django 1.10 solo se remueve la opción de usar el path punteado de Python.

> The ability to use a dotted Python path for the LOGIN_URL and
>   LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL settings is removed.

Este sera removido.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'path.a.vistas.login'
```

Pero aun puedes usar

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'
```

o

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
```

Notas:

- [Django 1.10 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/)